# Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources' on Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, salesforce

I have an issue with Ionic command : **Ionic build android**

[Here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/project/mobile-sdk-hybrid-apps/mobilesdk-hybrid-apps-04) the tutorial Salesforce i'm following to create an app connected to the Salesforce API. (contact, etc.).

Now, when i mudt build android, I have this issue :

```
:processDebugResources
/home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/sf__icon').

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> 
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:

    /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/android.jar -M /home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.ionicframework.ionicapp508454 -0 apk --output-text-symbols /home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/symbols/debug

  Error Code:

    1

  Output:

    /home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/sf__icon').

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.305 secs

Error: /home/r.**/Workspace/IonicApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I restart the tutorial 2 times and i still have this error. Maybe because I do an Android App and not an Ios like the tutorial.

What is this file missing and where is it supposed to be?

If you need the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ionicframework.ionicapp508454"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="18"
    android:versionName="0.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.ionicframework.ionicapp508454.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.ionicframework.ionicapp508454.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/sf__icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:manageSpaceActivity="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.ManageSpaceActivity" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.ionicframework.ionicapp508454" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.GCMIntentService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.ui.SalesforceDroidGapActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Some info:

- I create an Android App.
- Cordova-android is version 5.0.0 because 6.0.0 do a mismatch issue with the api salesforce.
- I'm a beginner with Ionic/Cordova and mobile dev. Maybe the solution is oubvious.

Comment: The error output suggests that the build just fails due to a missing icon resource: `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/sf__icon').` Maybe a naming issue, have you accidentally  added a second underscore or is the icon just not present? ;)

Comment: Indeed but where this file is supposed to be ? I never use XML so i don't know where he is looking for this file. I'll paste another random icon just to be able to run 'Ionic build'

Comment: ah okay - so the `@drawable/` notation references `res/drawable` in your Android project, so for giving it a try the easiest way would probably be to place a dummy icon in this folder.. however just checked the Salesforce SDK repo, and indeed the file is referenced in their XML file, but no icon is included... strange though!

Comment: My fault, to be fair, Salesforce has included the icons, you can find them here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin/tree/master/src/android/libs/SalesforceSDK/res so maybe check if the plugin is installed correctly (maybe remove it and add it again?). Surely it's still possible that the plugin itself contains an error though. You could also try running `cordova prepare` once before trying another build, could transfer the icons as well!

Comment: l had no drawable folder in res and I have a Drawable file in /plugins/com.salesforce/src/android/libs/salesforceSDK/res/drawable where i created a sf__icon. I copy-paste it where you said and it's the beginning of the solution. The error message change for another missing files.  Thx OClyde, it was res/drawable!

Comment: Added the answer as an actual answer to this post so that others find the solution easier! Would be grateful if you marked it as the correct answer! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error output suggests that the build just fails due to a missing icon resource: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/sf__icon').

The SalesforceSDK includes those files though, however they do not seem to be added to the Android project correctly:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin/tree/master/src/android/libs/SalesforceSDK/res

Copy-pasting might resolve the problem though, still wondering why the plugin does not add the drawables as expected in the res/drawable folder!

Comment: This is the solution to this problem. Thx OClyde